# IE 8 debugger doesn't stop on TypeError

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer-8

I'm trying to get an angular.js/jQuery app running in IE8. I mostly have things working, but it spews a lot of console errors:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is null or not an object
```

These errors in the developer tools don't have a source location (file & line) associated with them, and the debugger doesn't break on errors when these are being thrown, even if "Break on Error" is enabled.

Other than disabling portions of my code to search for the cause, is there any way to figure out where this is coming from? I'm getting dozens of them in every Angular digest cycle, so it's not as straightforward as figuring out what page actions cause them.

It's not obvious what, if anything, they're breaking on the page, but I haven't yet had the ability to test the whole thing, so it's hard to conclude they're benign; even if they are, I'd prefer to get rid of them; they're noisy and I'm concerned that they may be visible to the user under some IE error-handling configurations.

Comment: Do you have unit tests? If you can connect IE8 to karma it might help you narrow it down?

Comment: I recall Angular had various shims for IE.  Are you using all the appropriate shimming mechanisms?  Also, I've found the guide (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie) to be helpful.  Lastly, AngularJS 1.3 dropped support for IE8: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie

Comment: You can try to isolate place where this happen (you can even look into Angular source code), which function throw it and then wrap it with try..catch, you should have `stack` property on `error` object (not sure if IE have it). When I was debugging on Android 2.3 (without any debuger) I fetch all my files using ajax eval it and wrap with try..catch and then print the result into pre tag.

Answer (score 1):

Though I've never used it, I've heard that [DebugBar](http://www.debugbar.com/) is an improvement over the standard IE8 developer tools.

Also, as JJZabkar mentioned in the question comments, Angular versions below 1.3 require certain shims to be in place to work with IE8 or below.

Another thing to be aware of, which is also described at that link he provided (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie), is IE8's lack of support for custom element tags, which will foil any use of element-based directives (possibly causing errors) if you do not take certain measures.